# SharePoint 2013 search log error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search

The search not work, I look the logs an see this error:
"The server is not available and could not be accessed. It is likely to be disconnected from the network"

How I fix this?

Comment: I checked and user have permission to access all itens of the log

Comment: You need too give us a lot more info in order to help you. Can you provide additional info from the ULS logs? Looking in the SSA are all components running?

Comment: All services and related research components are working. Only stopped indexing the latest. Got to check the error log that

Comment: Not found the answer. Added a new source of research and sent incremental run, ran al.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, but the incremental index worked